# "I’m going to have to let you go". why the words "going" and "have" are stand together in sentence?

Tags: grammar

> That person is "going to let someone go"

or

> he "have/must let someone go"?

Why are the words "going" and "have" stand together in sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly?
have to = assumes "now"
gonna have to = not now, but soon?

Comment: Yup. Going to has nothing to do with "walking", but "moves" the other verb (here: have) into the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to have to let you go.

This is a quite an intricate little sentence, so let's have a look at the components:

- going to (do sth.)
  Expresses the future - in this case, a very probable event.
- have to  (do sth.)
  A strong obligation to do something, caused by external factors.
- let so. go
  Is an idiom, an euphemistic form of saying to fire someone or to terminate a contract.

So, in very plain English:

> I will fire you soon.